# How to create Node server only for POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to create a Node server only for receiving POST requests. With the information in the body of the request, I need to create a system call. How do I do so? So far, I only have:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser);
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('POST /');
    console.dir(req.body);
});

port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port)
```

However, when I make a POST request to 127.0.0.1:3000, the body is undefined.

var request = require('request');

```
request.post(
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
    { form: { "user": "asdf" } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: What does you actual POST-request look like?

Comment: which version of node you are using?

Comment: @Tholle - I edited the question body with the Post request (in Node).

Comment: use bodyParser as a middleware as shown below, and do tell if you're still facing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a middleware problem here. The `express.bodyparser()` middleware is deprecated in Express 4.x. This means you should be using the standalone `bodyparser` middleware.

Oddly enough, you're importing the correct middleware by doing:

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`

However, you should be using it differently. Take a look at [the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) and the example given:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); 

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); 

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing     application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(multer()); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
res.json(req.body);
})
```

In the newest version of express, express.bodyParser is not used. See the [reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html)